# Worklight 6.1 - IWAP Analytics - Execution without root?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have got a question regarding IWAP and Worklight 6.1.

I have look on forums, official documentation but cannot found the answer.

We are using Worklight 6.1 and IWAP and it seems that the IWAP installation should be done in root, otherwise it doesn't work

**> Do you know which folders or installed librairies required to be root during installation ?**

Once installed with the following command line, the target analytics folder is in root permissions (wl-analytics)

./setup.sh stand-alone -n WLCLUSTER_DEV -s /opt/IBM/wl-analytics -d /opt/IBM/wl-analytics/data -l /opt/IBM/wl-analytics/logs -o 2000

See http://snag.gy/Q8r4A.jpg for screenshot

If I start IWAP with a no root user, IWAP is not started and I have got the following errors :

```
[wladmin@localhost wl-analytics]$ ./iwap.sh start
./iwap.sh: line 30: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
IWAP search engine starting ...
Waiting for search engine to become active.
Waiting for search engine to become active.
Waiting for search engine to become active.
Waiting for search engine to become active.
Waiting for search engine to become active.
Waiting for search engine to become active.
Waiting for search engine to become active.
Waiting for search engine to become active.
Waiting for search engine to become active.
Waiting for search engine to become active.
Waiting for search engine to become active.
Waiting for search engine to become active.
Waiting for search engine to become active.
Waiting for search engine to become active.
Waiting for search engine to become active.
IWAP search engine unable to start. Please look at search engine logs.
IWAP console starting ...
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain for ServerName
(13)Permission denied: httpd: could not open error log file /opt/IBM/wl-analytics/HTTPServer/logs/error_log.
Unable to open logs
IWAP console unable to start. Please look at the web server logs.
```

It seems to be due to permissions on the wl-analytics folder so I have changed the permissions of this folder with : chown -R wladmin:adm /opt/IBM/wl-analytics

After that, I am able to launch IWAP as wladmin user (no root user), IWAP works fine but I have some warnings in the prompt :

```
[wladmin@localhost wl-analytics]$ ./iwap.sh start
./iwap.sh: line 30: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
IWAP search engine starting ...
Waiting for search engine to become active.
Waiting for search engine to become active.
IWAP search engine started.
IWAP console starting ...
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain for ServerName
IWAP console started.
```

**> Everything seems to work but do you know if there are some side effects?**

**> Do you know why also should be launch IWAP as root if I do not change the folder permissions of IWAP**

**> Do you have a technical documentation about IWAP ?**

**> Do you know how to change the port of IWAP without reinstalling IWAP ?**

**> Do you know how to monitor the IWAP module ?**

I am asking these questions since we are implementing IWAP on Worklight 6.1 for a project and the project is blocked due to this (root execution of IWAP).

Thanks a lot.

Mat

Answer (score 0):

**Everything seems to work but do you know if there are some side effects?**
Are you sure everything worked? Were you able to access the analytics console successfully? I've attempted to install IWAP as a non root user and was unsuccessful.

**Do you know why also should be launch IWAP as root if I do not change the folder permissions of IWAP**
My only guess is that the installation is doing things that can only be done by the root user.

**Do you have a technical documentation about IWAP ?**
The only documentation I know about is [here](http://engtest01w.francelab.fr.ibm.com:9090/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_analytics_overview.dita)

**Do you know how to change the port of IWAP without reinstalling IWAP ?** 
I don't think it is possible without re installing since the port is defined at install time. In Workight 6.2, this port can be changed via JNDI properties.

**Do you know how to monitor the IWAP module ?**
I'm sorry, I don't think I understand what you're asking for here.

Comment: Yes I have installed it as root, then changed permissions of the IWAP destination folder (wl-analytics) using chown -R wladmin:adm wl-analytics, and then started IWAP with wladmin user (no root user). The dashboard works fine but I am wondering if there are some side effects.

Comment: Regarding the monitoring of IWAP, my question was "how to check that the search engine is up? how to check that the IHS included in IWAP is operationnal? Which logs file should be monitored?"